# VSTS Extension - Release definition data, environment ids

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am developing web extension for VSTS. I am using vss sdk of Microsoft. 
I got some issue.

You can see on the image that there is new line - `App insights Settings`
This pop up appears on clicking on 3 dots near every release definition on page of list of all releases.

[image]

This button navigates user to some environment of some specific release.
Example of link:
`https://ozcodedev.visualstudio.com/OzCode/_releaseProgress?releaseId=372&_a=release-environment-logs&environmentId=850`

The problem that I do not know how to fetch list of releases and environments for building this link. 
How can I get them on page `All release pipelines`. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So after working 2 days on this issue I found solution.

1.It is possible to fetch data that I wanted on Client Side. For this I used Microsoft's library `vss-web-extension-sdk`. Install it - `npm install vss-web-extension-sd --save`.

2.Add relevant scopes to your `vss-extension.json`. In my case the problem was - that I needed data that relates to managing of VSTS user releases. So after Including `"vso.release_manage"` to my `scopes` array I stopped to got `401 Unauthorized error` because access token was changed according to new scopes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/manifest?view=vsts#scopes

In this documentation you can check which scope controls which resources that can be accessed by your extension.

Answer (score 1):

Through the GUI it is not possible to get all the release ids and the environment ids for each step. However this is possible through the [VSTS APIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases?view=vsts-rest-4.1). You could use the release endpoint to and iterate to obtain your release id

```
https://{accountName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.1-preview.6
```

Once you have the release id you can use it like so

```
https://{accountName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=4.1-preview.6
```

Within the returned JSON you can follow iterate the path `environment[n].id` to obtain the environment id.

You can then construct the link using this information.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use our [ts/js clients](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api) to get whatever you want for your experience.

We have extensive documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases?view=vsts-rest-4.1). Let me know if you are blocked anywhere.